# React.jsx vs React.js as a filename extenison for component creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

As a part of my react development, i came across components which is a part of JSX. I saw some script files were created with .jsx extension and again the same concept of components were used with .js extension.

For rendering the components, reactDOM.render() which is same in both the cases.

But script type for .jsx is `<script src="text/jsx">`

and for .js is `<script src="text/babel">`

As JSX acts a syntactic sugar for creating elements in the form of components. And Babel is used as a transpiler to covert component to elemental form.

My question is do we have any criteria to use either one of these at particular instant of time?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rule of a thumb is:

- **index.js** for js logic
- **nameOfComponent.jsx** for render function

I explained it in depth here:
https://hackernoon.com/building-modular-interfaces-a4e4076b4307

and here is boilerplate you can use:
https://github.com/metaphorical/quantum-blox

Comment: Thanks for the link. i do get some more important information. But still my question is not solved. And i do see some ES6 syntax in that.